# How can I get KODI and a Python script to run at the same time?

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi4, kodi, raspbian-buster

I have created a small program in Python 3 (3.7.3) to monitor the supply voltage of the uninterruptible power supply (UPS). If the voltage is switched off, the system should be shut down in a controlled manner.

- First I called KODI (18.7) and the Python script from 'autostart'

```
(*/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart*)
```

and realised that only KODI is running and the script is not.

- Then I called KODI from my script after running two monitoring loops. When KODI started, the script froze and continued exactly where it left off when KODI was stopped.
- I then started KODI from the menu (Menu --> Entertainment media --> KODI) and, strangely enough, both programs worked in parallel.

Comment: But that is the question or problem exactly ?

Comment: Yes, in the end I would like to start both programmes from the "autostart". Perhaps there are certain commands that can be added to the instruction to make this possible. I have added the following lines to the autostart file:
`code`
@lxterminal -e python3 /home/pi/pi4/python/usvStromPi3Status.py 
@kodi
`code`
And from the Python script I have called KODI as follows:
`code`
 cycle += 1
 if cycle == 3:
  subprocess.run(['kodi'])
`code`

Comment: SOLVED - Someone on KODI forum told me to run the script as a service. So I did.